# Html Accesskey for checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox, access-keys

i have given access key for my checkbox to get focus by using the shortcut key.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkStudent" data-bind="checked: isStudent" accesskey="s"/>
```

but when i am typing the access key ie (Alt + s) i am getting the checkbox as uncheked. But i need just a focus on that. Can you suggest me any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

When you use the accessKey property that will select the element when the key is pressed. To focus the element need to write the some script on the element. This may help to u.
[Adding keyboard-accessible actions to static HTML elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR29)

Answer (score 1):

The effects of using keys defined with `accesskey` are underspecified in specifications, and they vary across browsers. Generally, `accesskey` is now regarded as a problem, not part of a solution, at least from accessibility point of view. Normally, people who would benefit from `accesskey` if it were properly defined and implemented can work with forms using keyboard navigation and functionality (e.g., tab key for tabbing), if the form is well-designed.